# Why Chrome does not trust SSL?

Tags: php, ssl

SSL is installed to my VPS correctly. I want to use ssl in some pages of my website. Every form in these pages are starting with "https://", too. But browsers don't accept it.

What are the possible reasons?

[image: SSL Problem]

Comment: Click the lock icon and view information on the certificate. It's often something like the cert's domain is `example.com` while you're using it on `www.example.com`.

Comment: Do you load resources on your page through a non-secured connection? Do you load e.g. images through `http://`?

Comment: Open the console. You may be downloading resources (such as javascript files) from a non secured site.

Comment: Or a needed intermediate certificate is not installed on the web server, if your cert requires a chain.

Comment: Some of the images, yes. Is this the problem?

Comment: It is most likely. Browsers require you to load *all* content through a secured connection, otherwise they will display a warning message.

Comment: @ekrembk Yes, this is the main issue most of the times.

Comment: Thank you all everyone. You were really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a number of reasons. Last time I got it on my site was when I was using an iframe with external content and a flash widget loaded via an external javascript. Both were accessed via HTTP and messed my site's trustworthiness.

So. Check all your external content: javascripts, widgets, iframes, images, stylesheets... You may be loading them via HTTP, which in turn may make Chrome claim the SSL certificate has a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would try checking it via something like this first : http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Answer (score 0):

You might also try running curl -verbose https://yourlink.com from the console in order to get detailed printout of where the hiccups are.